# MongoDB Realm / App Services Swift Login Synchronisation not working, Users need to login every time

Tags: swift, mongodb, realm, mongodb-realm

I've build an SwiftUI App that uses MongoDB Realm (or now App Services) as a backend. Users can authenticate using email/password, AppleID or Google.

In the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/users/#std-label-users-and-authentication) and by [mongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/is-there-a-remember-me-in-the-login/183999) it says that realm automatically manages the login and the session in the sdk. However, after closing the app (without logout ofc) and reopening, the currentUser obj of my realm object is nil.

Is there any configuration necessary to the realm instance in the app or the console?

My code is quite simple i assume. After declaring my realm on on app Top Level with

```
let watchlistRealmApp = RealmSwift.App(id: "<my-app-ID>")
```

i check in my LoginViewModel if there is a user:

```
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {

// UserInteraction
@Published var inProgress = false
@Published var errorMessage = ""
@Published var isLoggedIn: Bool = false

var email: String?
var password: String?

// UserMetaData
private var contactEmail: String?

init() {
    if watchlistRealmApp.currentUser?.isLoggedIn != nil || watchlistRealmApp.currentUser != nil {
        print("loggedIn = true")
        self.isLoggedIn = true
    }
}
```

so i can show or hide my LoginView in my ContentView

```
   if loginVm.isLoggedIn == false {
                LoginView()
            } else {
                HomeView()
            }
```

As explained, the expected behaviour would be that the SDK persists the information from the user and auto-logins to the users session. However the currentUser object is nil after closing and re-opening the app.

I saw that in the simulator, without closing but just building new it works. But in TestFlight or after "real" close of the app, i need to login, again.

Comment: A couple of things. First, rest assured that Realm persists the user authentication, as long as there was an [active network connection](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/users/authenticate-users/#offline-login) the last time they logged in. All that's needed is this `if let user = <your app>.currentUser { //do something with the user`. Perhaps the LoginViewModel is being called after some other activity? Can the currentUser check be temporarily moved to the initial view and see what the result is?

Comment: As you suggested it was a timing issue with the LoginVM. Thanks for ppointing that out.